# 'could not load type' error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a WCF service. now, I need to create a client that consumes my service. when I try to add a service reference from Visual Studio, this is what I get an error message :

```
"Could not load type 'System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetSchemaImporterExtensionFS35'
 from assembly 'System.Design,Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'".
```

here's the signature of my service :

```
public void SaveBookInDB(byte[] bytesToSave,bool append,Guid guid,String bookname,String contenttype)
```

I tried using the svcutil.exe at the command-line and I get this :

```
"Error : An error occured in the tool. Error : The type initializer for 
'OptionProcessingHelper' threw an exception.
Could not load type 'System.DateTimeOffset' from assembly 'mscorlin, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral,PublickKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'."
```

I don't know how to solve this. can anyone help me please ?

even after reinstalling Visual Studio, I still get the same problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What data do you have in your service? Note that `DataSet` isn't necessarily a good fit for WCF...

Comment: what do you mean ? I'm not sure i'm getting you. I'm not using DataSets.

Comment: Hence my question; what *does* your service look like? The fact that it is trying to load `TypedDataSetSchemaImporter` suggests `DataSet`...

Comment: ok, thanks. I just edited the question, have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by reinstalling my System and then reinstalling Visual Studio. and it now Works ! Great !

Comment: It's frustrating that this solution is what works for so many errors.

Answer (score 0):

With the question update; if that is the only method in the service (and assuming you don't have any exotic base-classes etc), then I conclude that your VS install is borked. Do you have another machine you can try from? Also, check that your method has the appropriate attributes etc, but that shouldn't cause the problem shown.

Have you tried using [`svcutil.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) at the command-line? It is very easy, and hopefully won't have this problem.

Comment: I tried using the svcutil.exe at the command-line and I get this :
"Error : An error occured in the tool. Error : The type initializer for 'OptionProcessingHelper' threw an exception.
Could not load type 'System.DateTimeOffset' from assembly 'mscorlin, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublickKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'."

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when Interface declaration differs to the implementation of the Service. For example, a function is declared in the Interface and it is implemented, but there is a parameter type discrepancy between the declaration and implementation. Then there can be no error in building the project, but attempt to Update Service Reference would fail.